# Issues while trying to use Maybe

Tags: haskell, option-type

I made the following Haskell function that checks the maximum consecutive occurrences of `Orange` on a list:

```js
import Data.Maybe
data Fruit = Apple | Orange
findMaxSubStr :: [Fruit] -> Maybe Int

findMaxSubStr xs = val xs 0 0
    where val [] prev current = (max prev current)
          val (Apple:xs) prev current = val xs (max prev current) 0
          val (Orange:xs) prev current = val xs prev (current + 1)
```

I'm now trying to integrate Maybe type, in case the occurrences are 0. For example, I want `[]` and `[Apple, Apple]` to produce `Nothing` instead of `0`. How should I proceed?

Moreover, instead of using the prebuilt `max` function, what's the best way to proceed in case I want to create my own function in order to check the max value?

Comment: I'd say that 0 is a perfectly reasonable answer to the question, "what the maximum consecutive occurrences of Orange on this list?".  Given that you have such a function, you could just call it and compare the answer with 0:

Comment: Adding a `Maybe` wrapper is a good idea when you have the same value (e.g. `0`) returned for two different reasons. I.e. when you want to distinguish `Nothing` and `Just 0`. Here, after you add the wrapper, you will never return `Just 0`. In such case, there is little to gain in adding the wrapper. Concretely, would you like to have `length :: [a] -> Maybe Int` instead of the regular one?

Comment: `max x y = if x <= y then y else x` from [source](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/src/GHC-Classes.html#Ord), I can't think of better custom build function for that simple logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't get why you make it that hard: simply use `scanl` to determine the "consecutive counts", then apply `maximum` on it, and in case the result is `0`, return `Nothing`, else `Just ...`:

```
findMaxSubStr fruits | maxc == 0 = Nothing
                     | otherwise = Just maxc
    where maxc = maximum counts
          counts = scanl f 0 fruits
          f x Orange = x+1
          f _ _      = 0
```

This being said I don't get why you want to return `Nothing`. In this case zero is a perfectly valid answer. `Maybe` is usually used to return some kind of "exception" answer. Like `find` that might fail to find an element.

**The code works as follows:**

first we perform a `scanl`. [`scanl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) passes some sort of *accumulator* through a list: for each element it calls the function (here `f`) with the accumulator and the object in the list. The result is the "new" accumulator. This result is then returned as an element in the resulting list, and reused to pass the accumulator to the next element. So in general it is something like:

```
-- example of scanl for three elements (this is not its real implementation)
scanl f acc0 [xa,xb,xc] = [acc1,acc2,acc3]
    where acc1 = f acc0 xa
          acc2 = f acc1 xb
          acc3 = f acc2 xc
```

In this case the accumulator is the *length of the sequence of `Orange`s **thus far***: so `[Orange,Apple,Apple,Orange,Orange,Orange,Apple,Orange]` will map on `[1,0,0,1,2,3,0,1]` this result will be stored in `counts`.

Now we calculate the `maximum` of that list `counts`. So the result - `maxc` - is the maximum of the `counts` and thus the length of the *longest* (not the current) sequences of oranges.

Next in the function definition we inspect whether that value is equal to `0`. If that is the case, we return `Nothing`. Otherwise we return `Just maxc`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the code in the `where`? I'm still a newbie in functional programming

Comment: @AndiPavllo: better?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a definition of your `findMaxSubStr` function which uses a fold to directly calculate the length of the longest sequence of oranges in the list without creating an intermediate list:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

findMaxSubStr :: [Fruit] -> Maybe Int
findMaxSubStr fruits =
  case numOranges of
    0 -> Nothing
    n -> Just n
  where
    numOranges = uncurry max $ foldl' countOranges (0, 0) fruits
    countOranges t Orange = (1+) <$> t
    countOranges (x,y) _ = (max x y, 0)
```

In [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) you can find a discussion on when to use `foldl'` versus using `foldr` or `foldl`, together with examples showing how these fold functions work.

A tuple is used to track the length of Orange sequences. First value keeps the length of the longest sequence found, second element stores the length of the current sequence.

Original implementation of `where` block was:

```
where
  numOranges = fst $ foldl' countOranges (0, 0) fruits
  countOranges (x, y) Orange = let y' = y+1 in (max x y', y')
  countOranges (x, _) _  = (x, 0)
```

I've edited the answer following @Ryan suggestions (see comment below) and here are some notes describing how the solution works now:

`countOranges t Orange = (1+) <$> t` takes advantage of the fact that 2-tuples are functors and the `<$>` operator applies the function passed as first parameter (i.e. `(1+)` in our case) to the second element of the 2-tuple. Thus, in the counter `(x, y)` we increase `y` while finding oranges, without touching `x`, i.e. we are calculating the length of the current orange sequence (when we find one).

When we find an apple, `countOranges (x,y) _ = (max x y, 0)` will update the `x` in `(x,y)` and reset `y` to `0`. You can see that `x` will hold the length of the longest sequence of oranges found so far.

If the longest sequence of oranges occurs at the end of the fruits list, the update of `x` described in previous paragraph will not happen. That's the reason we still need `numOranges = uncurry max $ ...` to get the max value from the `(x, y)` tuple returned by `foldl'`.

Comment: The goal is to count the longest sequence of consecutive `Orange`s, though, not the total number of oranges.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, I've edited the answer to provide the length of the longest sequence of oranges now.

Comment: Could do `numOranges = uncurry max $ …` and `countOranges t Orange = (1+) <$> t` and `countOranges (x, y) _ = (max x y, 0)` to make fewer comparisons.

Comment: Great @Ryan Answer updated according your suggestions.